# Openshift: get commit or build id during build/deploy?

Tags: git, openshift

I'm building an Openshift app that downloads a directory full of dependencies and backs up the existing database on every build. I'd like to name the directory and the database dump with the commit id (or the build id), but since there's no actual repository on the remote, I can't just use something like `git rev-parse --short HEAD` to get it.

Can anybody think of a way to retrieve it during build?

--
Chris

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to achieve the same.

Comment: I typed `find . -name .git` into the console while ssh'ing onto my OpenShift VM and did not find anything. So probably this can't be achieved by a `git` command executed on the VM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I was able to do for this was to just create a backup with a reasonably precise timestamp (e.g. something like backup-201411042116.tar.gz). There's consequently no direct connection to a specific commit, but for my app at least it was sufficient (rolling back the app is a pretty rare occurrence).

If you want, you can also make manual backups from your local machine using the `rhc` command line tools prior to a commit. See `﻿rhc snapshot save --help` for details.